# How to solve nested async database calls in Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, function, async-await, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get a list of objects and for each object there is a record in another collection which has to be called also. Both requests return promises and my question is, how to "wait" for the inner promises to be fulfilled before the next outer promises are done.

This is the code:

```
export async function getAllCompanies(req: Request, res: Response) {
   try {
        const listCompanies = await db.collection('companies').get()
        const companies = listCompanies.docs.map(async doc => {
            const data = doc.data()
            const location = await db.collection('locations').doc(data.locationId).get()
            const locationData = location.data()
            return {
                id: doc.id,
                name: data.name,
                address: locationData ? locationData.address : null,
                zipCode: locationData ? locationData.zipCode : null,
                city: locationData ? locationData.city : null,
                country: locationData ? locationData.country : null,
                email: data.email,
                phoneNumber: data.phoneNumber,
                type: data.type,
                createTime: doc.createTime.toDate(),
                lastUpdateTime: data.lastUpdateTime
            }
        })

        return res.status(200).send({ companies })
   } catch (err) {
       return handleError(res, err)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
const resolvedCompanies = await Promise.all(companies);
return res.status(200).send({companies: resolvedCompanies});
```

just before the `return res.status(...)`. This will wait for all of the promises you `map`-ed into the list of companies to resolve before returning and return the values instead of the promises.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.